# Using array.reduce to sequentially fire async functions without Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I can execute asynchronous functions one after another like this:

```js
function asyncFn(e, cb) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e);
      res();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.reduce(
  (chain, e) => chain.then(()=>asyncFn(e)),
  Promise.resolve()
);
```

Is it possible to do the same using callbacks instead of resolving the promise?

Comment: No, not really. It's the async/promise part that lets immediate return from asyncFn and continues execution. If you take out the Promise/Async part of this code then it needs to wait for each call to asyncFn to complete before it can continue execution. If that doesn't explain it for you let me know and ill try and do a better job of explaining it. ** You could do it with setTimeout but that would be a mess to maintain.

Comment: setTimeout is there as an example of an async function, if that's what you're talking about

Comment: What's the drawback of resolving the promise?

Comment: No drawbacks really, just curious to see the possibly harder answer

Comment: reduce isn't really the right tool for the job. It'd be a rather poor comparison of doing things with promises vs without.

Comment: then what is? @KevinB

Comment: a recursive function, effectively acting as a queue processor.

Comment: Recursive functions aren't exactly the best in case of performance, are they.. Provided I had several or even hundreds of quick async calls I had to run sequentially (e.g. calling a function for every frame of a movie), that would clog the memory pretty fast

Comment: ***It's an async function***. performance is irrelevant. The performance is 99% dependant on the async portion of the operation that is likely out of your control in the real world.

Comment: The performance of the javascript that initiates the task pales in comparison to how long the async task itself takes by very large margins.

Comment: Let's say I have to call 100 async functions one after another.. The first function called would sit in the memory until the last one has finished, isn't that right?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Async recursion is not "real" recursion, as the recursive call happens in the async callback the call stack unwinds and the memory gets released

Answer (score -2):

Sure, but its a bit more complicated:

```
const logLater = (msg, time, cb) => setTimeout(() => (console.log(msg), cb()), time);

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.reduceRight((next, el) => () => logLater(el, 1000, next), () => console.log("all done!"))();
```

Or in multiple lines :/ :

```
function logLater(msg, time, cb) {
 setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(msg);
   cb();
 }, time);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.reduceRight(function(next, el) {
 return function current() {
   logLater(el, 1000, next);
 };
}, function() { })();
```

Building up the callback chain goes backwards, so logging the `5` will be wrapped in a function that logs it when called, then that function is passed into the wrapper of `4` which will call it when `4` was logged, that wrapper of `4` is passed as `next` to the wrapper of `3` and so on.

---

If you however just want to do a certain task for all elements of an array and wait for the previous callback, you could do that with a function that calls itself:

```
function logLater(msg, time, cb) {
 setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(msg);
   cb();
 }, time);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

(function  next(i) {
   logLater(arr[i], 1000, function done() {
     if(i < arr.length - 1) next(i + 1);
   });
})(0);
```

Comment: This has got to be some of the hardest code to follow I've ever seen. I am not a fan of this trend where everything has to be one line and impossible to easily follow. This is overly complicated for the sake of looking sleek and 'fancy' and probably has OP more confused than when they started.

Comment: @adam then add your own answer with code that is more easy to follow :)

Comment: Or you could just stop trying to be trendy and cool and just help the guy.

Comment: Couldn't understand anything... no identation, everything in one line

Comment: @adam thats neither "trendy" nor "cool", thats just how I write code. This is far more complicated with regular loops as you would have to create closures etc. so this is probably the easiest way of doing what the OP did with callbacks.

Comment: You're calling the accumulator in reverse order and have to use `reduceRight` to make it right again.. I think this could be done in a regular order with `reduce`?

Comment: @mateusz `.reverse().reduce(...)` maybe?

Comment: I'm talking about you treating the accumulator as the next and not as the previous

Comment: @mateusz thats not possible as you cannot call back a function that is not existing yet.